token swaps on amm supported dexs on solana
i am a new to solana development just started exploring it yesterday before that i am doing development on etherum and other evm compatible chains from last 2 years.
i have a question for people who have been doing development on the solana chain.
i want to build a swapping dapp on solana which will help users swap there tokens against another token but i have this very specific requirement that the user should be able to specify the pool as well so suppose you have the 30 pools of the same pairs usdc/wsol or wsol/usdc but out of those 30 pairs user should explicitly knows that with which pool he wants to use for swap.
is it possible on solana chain to also specicify the pool address by choice that dapp targets the specific pool.
i don't want to build another onchain program for the interaction will do it through the solana web3.js
any input would be appreciated .
looking forward to a engaging thread.

You can definitely specify the pool address by choice -- you just need to design your AMM to do it. Even SPL's token-swap allows this: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token-swap
